# Loading can be cancelled by upward drag

Tags: bug, android-app

1. Go to Stack Overflow or any other site.
2. With the loading progress bar is visible, hold the screen and drag upward.
3. The loading progress bar is hidden and a blank screen is shown.

   > [image]

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: Motorola
- Device Model: XT1706
- OS Version: 6.0 (XT1706_S131_160905_ROW)

Comment: Confirmed on OnePlus One, app 1.0.89 as well

Comment: Huh! Happened to me by mistake today, thought it's just random glitch.